# Windows 8 Javascript: Listview invoke trouble

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I've been struggling between using C# and Html to make a windows 8 app. But I decided to use Html because of certain functions. But I've been having trouble getting which Listview Item/Element/Child is selected if any. This is what I have in my Html:

```
<div id="shapeListItem" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none;">
   <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
      <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
   </div>
</div>

<div id="shapes" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemDataSource : shapeTemplate.itemList.dataSource, 
       itemTemplate: select('#shapeListItem'),
       tapBehavior: 'toggleSelect',
       selectionMode: 'single'}">
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
WinJS.Utilities.ready(function () { init(); });

function init() {
    var shapes = document.getElementById("shapes").winControl;
    //shapes.selected ???
}
```

I don't remember what all I've tried but I never got it to work.
I just want to get which item is selected and get the image uri from it. Or I could add another title or something to my data bindings, which appears to be working fine by the way. Thanks for looking at what I've got, if you have any other suggestions or methods for anything else it would be appreciated. Or if I need to post more code I'll do that.

Thanks again,
Stephen

EDIT: 
Ohh I've also tried adding a "onitemInvoke : 'handler'" but that came up with an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211852.aspx

Try:

```
function init() {
    var shapes = document.getElementById("shapes").winControl;
    // gets an array of the indices:
    var selectedIndices = shapes.selection.getIndices(); 
}
```

A trick I have for you is to do:

```
function init() {
    var shapes = document.getElementById("shapes").winControl;
    debugger;
    // gets an array of the indices:
    var selectedIndices = shapes.selection.getIndices(); 
}
```

Then add "shapes" to the watch window - You will be able to see the APIs.